# Does PhpStorm debugging require a local PHP server or just interpreter?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm 6.0.3 with the PHP (7.0.13) on Windows 7.
(i.e., I'm not using a full blown local server like XAMPP or MAMP. This is just simple PHP, no database, etc).

When I try to debug, PhpStorm reports:

> Connection xdebug was not established. Validate Installation.

When I validate it says Xdebug is installed.

I've tried:

- Disabling Firewall (just in case).
- Disabling antivirus
- Confirmed I'm "listening for php debug connections" (and also tried it with that off)

It occurred to me that maybe I need a "full blown" server (like XAMPP or MAMP).

Comment: No server is required. It's possible that: 1) your PhpStorm is too old to handle xdebug 2.4 (which is minimal version that supports PHP 7.0 and might have some nuances that your version is unaware; not sure) and/or 2) You just did not setup everything properly (e.g. missing paths mappings or whatever). Here are official manuals -- have a look if you did not yet and see if you can spot what you are doing differently: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm . You better provide some details 9screenshots or better screencast)